# List of Indeterminate forms in Mathematics

Tags: soft-question, indeterminate-forms

I know that ,

$1) \frac{0}{0}$

$2) \frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$

$4) 0 \times(\pm\infty) $ are Indeterminate forms.

But in measure theory  $ 0 \times(\pm\infty) =0 $

Are there any other indeterminate forms ? And Why ?

Comment: You can add $1^{\infty}$ and $0^0$ to that list.

Comment: There's also $\infty - \infty$, $\infty^0$

Comment: "Indeterminate form" really shouldn't be taken to have a hard, well-defined meaning.  Division by zero and general arithmetic with infinity is not allowed by the rules of algebra. "Indeterminate forms" are just expressions which naively substitute a limiting value for the limit variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a list of indeterminate forms usually encountered:

$$\frac{0}{0}$$
$$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

$$0 \cdot \infty$$
$$0^0$$
$$\infty - \infty$$
$$\infty^0$$
$$1^\infty$$

Why are they indeterminate?

[image]

Just in case this turns out to be helpful:

[image]

The sources of these images are:
1. https://www.math.brown.edu/~pflueger/math1a/lecture24.pdf

2. http://17calculus.com/limits/indeterminate-forms/

In case, you are starting off learning about indeterminate forms I suggest taking a look at the pdf above.
Hope this helps.

Comment: L'Hospital can only be used in indeterminate formats \frac{0}{0} and \frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}

Answer (score 1):

> Here are 7 indeterminate forms involving 0, 1, and ∞ that arise when evaluating limits

[image]

> — Fermat's Library (@fermatslibrary) [December 24, 2020](https://twitter.com/fermatslibrary/status/1342116200617271296?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

These are popularly known as *the seven deadly sins of calculus*.